# Can I secure myself from my ISP using a VPN server or other implementation only from my home?

Tags: networking, security, vpn, encryption

With the recent US government controversy I am interested in encrypting my traffic past my ISP. I know the conventional way to do this is with a VPN service, but my issue lies in that the only encryption I am guaranteed is between the client and the VPN node/server. So with something like this:

> Client -> Router -> ISP -> VPN -> Destination

I have no control over what's happening in the hops between "VPN" and "destination."

This brings up several questions:

1. How safe am I between "VPN" and "Destination?" Do I get any guarantees, or do I just have to trust the VPN service?
2. Is it possible to encrypt/secure myself with a VPN implemented in my own home (I particularly had a raspberry pi in mind)? I can only see it keeping my data safe only if I am connecting from the internet to my home network, but not the other way around. If I can't keep my outgoing traffic safe with an internal VPN, are there any other services I can implement in my home to protect my information?
3. If I am able to implement my own security service from within my home (hopefully with a VPN, but still open to other services), what security risks do I run in only having my free time vs a company that would probably have a handful of full time engineers? Are they negligible if my primary concern is ISP snooping?

Answer (score 2):

1. Not safe at all, unless the application you are using uses end-to-end encryption. You can't even trust the VPN service as they have no control of their upstream.
2. If you are only interested in accessing information on the networks you control, and your VPN is set up securely, this can work. You can set up this up in either direction if you use a pre-shared key.
3. If your only concern is ISP snooping, either option would work.  Also consider using TOR.

Be aware that your ISP would be aware you are using a VPN and could infer the kinds of activity you are engaged in based on the size and timing of packets.

Comment: For number 2, if I can only access the networks I can control, what exactly do you mean by "set up in either direction?" I am reading that as I would be able encrypt myself from my home out to the internet, which I think contradicts the former point.

Comment: think less about the encryption, and more on the tunnels. In this case, you would have two tunnels; one from your router to the VPN service provider, and one from your remote device to your home network. if you are in a coffee shop or whatever, you can connect to your home network, and then browse the Internet using the tunnel to the VPS. That way the traffic is protected from the coffee shop lan, the shop's ISP, and your ISP.  if your individual connections are encrypted (HTTPS, SSH, etc) then no party can see your traffic in the clear except the end system you are connecting to.

Comment: If https,ssh, etc are all considered tunnels then for the most part, the VPN sounds redundant?? I just checked all my browser tabs and don't see anything using http.

Comment: the value to the VPS is that with individual connections, an outside party can still see the unencrypted portions of the packet, so they know who its to, who its from, and information like URL requested. with a VPN they only see one "fat" connection, between you and the VPS, and can't tell that it is carrying three https connections, two http connections, is resolving DNS for a server, and participating in a bittorrent swarm for a file. The layering of encryption, tunnels inside of tunnels, is what provides end to end security.

Comment: in case that was insufficiently explicit, my point is that the entire packet is encrypted when using a VPN service, not just the data payload, so the ISP cant tell that you connected to Amazon at all. using just HTTPS without a VPN, they could tell what item you looked at.

Comment: Just to be 100% sure I understand, the VPS you mention can be in my home and still logically between my device and the ISP?

Comment: no. the VPN service endpoint absolutely must be outside your ISPs network in order to allow you to tunnel past the ISP. that is your outbound tunnel.  you can allow your remote devices to connect over VPN to your router for access to your home network, on the go, but that is a different tunnel (an inbound tunnel). inbound lets you access your home LAN and is on your router. outbound lets you access the internet, by tunneling to a endpoint outside your ISP.

Comment: @ryan - you might want to communicate the threat you are trying to mitigate and your usage case. VPNs just encrypt traffic between 2 points. If your threat is between those to points it could help, if it's outside then it probably won't.  Although https and SSH are encrypted and this intermediate parties will find it difficult to penetrate and see exactly what you did, they will still know what systems you communicated with, when, for how long, and be able to make inferences from that.

Answer (score 1):

1. `VPN` is a tunneling protocol which uses asymmetric cryptography, so:
   a. You **are safe** while the matter is the **content**.
   b. You are **NOT safe** while the matter is **IP addresses**.
2. If you want to **fake** your IP address you have to use some `VPN` service provider with his **own servers**. The *target machine* will not know your IP address (as it receives the IP address of one of `VPN` providers's servers) but your `VPN` service provider **WILL know it**.
3. Your `ISP` knows all your **communication** (*direct* targets' IP addresses - e. g. to your VPN provider) but he is **not able to decrypt the content** of your packets when they are encrypted and it and he is **not able** to to see **where you communication continues**.

All bad news. But see [Best Alternatives to Tor](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/best-alternatives-tor-12-programs-use-nsa-hackers-compromised-tor-project-376976).

Comment: its important to consider your adversary. you are correct, it takes very strong precautions indeed to contend with motivated nation-state level adversaries, but the situation is somewhat less dire if you are trying to simply avoid ISP snooping for the purposes of targeted advertising.